# Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch in magento 2

Tags: magento2, elasticsearch2

I am using Magento 2.4.5 and migrate to ubuntu 20.0.4 server. Installed elastic search but whenever run the command "php bin/magento setup:upgrade" getting following error

Could not validate a connection to Elasticsearch. Deprecated Functionality: Creation of dynamic property GuzzleHttp\Ring\Client\CurlMultiHandler::$_mh is deprecated in /opt/magento2/vendor/ezimuel/ringphp/src/Client/CurlMultiHandler.php on line 47

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting this error while installing. Do this in the file:-

> vendor/ezimuel/ringphp/src/Client/CurlMultiHandler.php

Add a variable on line no 28 in the same file

```
private $_mh;
```

now run the command again.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because in php 8 declaring a php variable dynamically (meaning without having public / protected / private $var before your constructor) is not possible anymore.

You are not supposed to have this error if you properly updated your module.

Check your composer.json version for the module ezimuel/ringphp (or the module requiring it). Then update your installation and it should be fine.